# Null propagation feature and Razor views

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-7.0

Hello I have a strange issue.

I use the null propagation feature in my razor pages like this

```
@(Model.ligneDossierLie?.dossier_id)
```

my project is based on 4.6.1 Framework and I use the last codeDom compiler 1.0.4 
and compiler 2.1.0

In the razor view I have an error message saying that I can't use a C# 6 feature with C#5.

But my project is using c#7 ....

I roll back to c#6 and it works fine.

Is someone know how to use c#7 in this case?

Thank you.

Web.config

```
 <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

compilerOptions="/langversion:6
```

was set on 7 and I roll back to 6. After that I didn't had the error anymore, My views are compiling and working correctly

Comment: Maybe [my similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42700380/107625) (including [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42712883/107625)) helps?

Comment: We use [StackExchange.Precompilation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation) for this; among the tools are bits that let you use C# vLatest in razor - like this: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation/blob/fd536b764983e2674a4549b7be6f26e971190c1e/Test.WebApp/Global.asax.cs#L32

Comment: @UweKeim I seen your question, but it's not the problem in my case. Thank you

Comment: @MarcGravell Actualy there's no standard way to use c#7 and razor engine with full features?

Comment: I just installed the StackExchange precompiler, and my project doesn't start anymore. csc error.

Comment: I had this problem this morning after updating CodeDom from 1.0.3 to 1.0.4 and the compiler from 2.0.1 to 2.1.0. I got the same error message in my Razor views, but it would compile just fine. I rolled back to the previous versions (1.0.3 and 2.0.1) and the error messages went away. Not the best solution, but I'll probably stick with the older versions until I can figure out how to upgrade without introducing those errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you can use C# 6 and C# 7 features indeed, although it needs a little work.

Add these packages:

- `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` (1.0.4 currently)
- `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` (2.1.0 currently)

Make sure you have this section in your `web.config`:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

And the required imports in your `csproj` file (should be there automatically, but check it):

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.4\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.4\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

And this target in it:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"> ... </Target>
```

---

Previous answer:

You can't use that since the ASP.NET MVC Razor view engine doesn't use Roslyn to compile your views. Hence it can't use features available from C# 6 and higher (the null propagation operator = C# 6).

You have to write your code in the pre-C# 6 style, or use another package to take advantage of an alternative view engine, like the one Stack Exchange created (thanks for [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) to point to that): https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation.

According to their documentation, you have to include the package:

```
Install-Package StackExchange.Precompilation.Build -Pre
```

and then put this at the end of your `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RoslynRazorViewEngine());
```

Comment: I don't understand.
Razor isn't using Roslyn to copile even if The last version of compiler and codeDom is installed?
In this cas could you tell me why it works with c#6 and doesn't with c#7 ?
Thanks

Comment: No, it does not work for C# 6. For 5 it does. It uses the old `csc` C# compiler.

Comment: Strange, I'm currently using null propagation feature so c#6 feature in my views and it works fine, but not with c#7.

I'll try your solution, but it's strange.

Comment: Where do you set it to be C# 6 then?

Comment: @Julien Cool. It works here. Are you sure you have the latest versions of `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` (1.0.4) and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` (2.1.0)? (Check the actual packages)

Comment: Yes I have both. I uninstalled stackExchange precompiler and now everything is fine with c#7 but I still get the error in visual studio even if the page compiles correctly.

Comment: That might be a problem with the VS support of ASP.NET MVC then. @Julien All C# 7 features work fine here.

Comment: I think so. It works fine here too now. Maybe there was some mess in packages.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, updated my answer to make sure all steps are there.

Comment: I didn't need to install `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`. Just adding the latest `DotNetCompilerPlatform` and setting `/langversion:7` worked for me.