# Asp.Net application - compilation error using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

My asp.Net Mvc app is running without any problems though Visual studio, but when I try to put in on IIS (I know how to do this), I get this very strange error:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502.
Show Detailed Compiler Output:
C:\WINDOWS\SysWoW64\inetsrv>C:\Test\Accone\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\16eb8311\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\8121a59c\00196fd3_a63ad001\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\ed18cf47\00c98d69_c354d001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\7538eabb\001eaa54_d010ce01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\e5802ac9\00b4f9b4_4a6acd01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\40110029\0084bdeb_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\2b26b1e1\00a3c7e5_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\03a8fb89\00b1eeec_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\180d0630\00fd29e8_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\75af2fc0\00c98d69_c354d001\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\6dc487a6\0071b0e2_1f6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\37f1b250\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\d751c874\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\ec2d5a6d\480547b9_5598d201\Aconne.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\c8e1112b\002a5be9_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\672d6da0\00e720c2_90c1cd01\Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\640def20\0071b0e2_1f6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\5e8bbd7e\00578cea_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\33684ec1\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\f8a102d0\cc144fbc_5698d201\App_global.asax.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\7dc103f3\00578cea_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\1cf62a4f\0000c41d_ffa6d001\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\8a4c27d1\0054c7db_a63ad001\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\622472c9\00578cea_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\d13792b0\003c57d9_fe82ce01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\81ebd97c\00a6d731_3527cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\001dbadd\0084bdeb_8647d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\edb37aba\0071b0e2_1f6ed001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\assembly\dl3\e3d3b0b9\0082b57b_49afcf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.a1ic32py.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.a1ic32py.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test\b7d6f7e8\579d0cdf\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.a1ic32py.1.cs"
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?
[I have tried this solution already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817870/asp-net-strange-compilation-error)

Comment: Is the APP built for 32 / 64 bit or both? Does your app pool allow 32 bit if it's built for 32 bit?

Comment: https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: maybe this can help you:
-1073741502 when printed as hexadecimal is c0000142 which I believe translates to:  "DLL Initialization Failed". 
could be a security/permissions issue or incorrect path

Comment: What actions are you doing to generate the error, and where do you see the error?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118750/known-issue-for-security-updates-3098779-and-3097997-for-the-.net-framework-4.5.1-and-4.5.2-after-you-install-the-.net-framework-4.6-on-windows-8.1,-windows-rt-8.1,-and-windows-server-2012-r2

Comment: I have given up and ended up precompiling project and removing compilator(Roslyn) sections from Web.config. I think that the problem is related to some .Net folders permission issues, but I couldn't figure to what exactly.